# I cannot understand the m=........line in the solution

Tags: c

So basically the question is,
Write a C program to convert a given integer (in seconds) to hours, minutes and seconds.
Test Data :
Input seconds: 25300 
Expected Output:
There are:
H:M:S - 7:1:40

Solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int sec, h, m, s;
    printf("Input seconds: ");
    scanf("%d", &sec);

    h = (sec/3600); 

    m = (sec -(3600*h))/60;

    s = (sec -(3600*h)-(m*60));

    printf("H:M:S - %d:%d:%d\n",h,m,s);

    return 0;
}`
```

I cannot understand the m=....line. Because I think 3600*h is in fact 's' and (s-s)/60 should be zero. I know I'm wrong but can you explain the solution in simpler terms.

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger and see what happens to the variable values.

Comment: Once you understand this, see what happens if you enter a negative number of seconds. Oops

Comment: The purpose of the question is no doubt to teach you how to use the `%` modulus operator.

Answer (score 2):

The division operator `/` with two integral arguments performs *integral* division: the result is an integer. Therefore, unless `sec` is exactly divisible by 3600, it is in general true that

```
sec != (sec / 3600) * 3600
```

To be exact, the following holds always<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
sec == (sec / 3600) * 3600 + (sec % 3600)
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As pointed out by @Bathsheba in comments, "always" excludes trap representations. So it's actually more like "holds for all valid numbers in `sec`"

Answer (score -1):

I'll write this down step by step using your input example, but the key thing you're missing is that all the variables are integers (`int`). Integers can't hold decimal values, so when doing integer division, the decimal part just gets cut off (i.e. the number is floored).

So for `sec = 25300`:

```
h = 25300/3600 = floor(7.02778) = 7
m = (25300-(3600*h))/60 = (25300-(3600*7))/60 = (25300-25200)/60 = floor(1.66667) = 1
s = (25300-(3600*h)-(m*60)) = (25300-(3600*7)-(1*60)) = floor(40.0) = 40
```

In other words, in the `m=...` line, you're subtracting the number of seconds that the number of **whole hours** (the number of times 3600 seconds passed) has from the **total number of seconds**, and then you're dividing those seconds by `60` to get the number of **full minutes** (the number of times 60 seconds passed).

NOTE: I used floor because that's the equivalent mathematical function for what's happening here, but the correct term for cutting off a decimal number to an integer is `trunc`